# 20.04 Frozen on Boot Screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, thinkpad

I recently dual-booted and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 1 alongside Windows 10 and the installation was working perfectly. The Nvidia proprietary driver was installed and I had no issues. I shutdown and upon trying to get back in to Ubuntu, it froze. I can get to the GRUB menu and successfully get back in to Windows 10. If I instead select Ubuntu from GRUB, it shows the Lenovo logo with the Ubuntu spin-loader. The spin loader disappears and it freezes there, so I never see the login screen. I have tried using nomodeset to get back in but it still freezes. I have also gone to the recovery mode and used dpkg to repair broken packages and update grub bootloader. Nothing has worked. This happened previously and I opted to delete the partition and reinstall, but I am facing the same problem with a fresh install. BIOS is updated and secure boot is off. What might the problem be?

Comment: related bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1876741